# New Relic traffic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I just added the New Relic add-on to my Rails Heroku app. As New Relic shows me real time response times for every minute or so, I'm wondering if this feature is producing much traffic on the site (or any extra cost)?

Comment: much traffic ? if your site is improved by performance and much faster then will it be relate to traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add instrumentation to your app, that instrumentation will effect process times as it collects and transmits data. How many times that instrumentation is invoked is effected by how you've written your code and the mode you've set it in (or so I imagine). I find it highly unlikely (and ironic) though that a gem used to measure performance would degrade a site's performance significantly.

New Relic describes their app modes as follows:

> **Production Mode**
>
> Low overhead instrumentation that captures detailed information on
>   your application running in production and transmits them to
>   newrelic.com where you can monitor them in real time.
>
> **Developer Mode**
>
> A Rack middleware that maps /newrelic to an application for showing detailed performance metrics on a page by page basis. Installed automatically in Rails applications.

While here (https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-agent-configuration) they give their opinion on developer mode in production:

> **developer_mode** - In Rails applications, having developer mode set to true installs the New Relic Developer Mode. This should generally be false in all environments except development mode since it introduces high overhead that would be intolerable in production.

I'm not sure what "*low overhead*", "*high overhead*", and "*intolerable*" mean in New Relic's context.

Personally, I have not noticed any overhead in the few low traffic apps I've used New Relic in.

Comment: FYI, if you're using the New Relic add-on for Heroku, "developer mode" will not be an option.

Comment: Developer mode is an option anytime you install the `newrelic_rpm` gem, but it's not designed to run in production anywhere (Heroku or otherwise). But in your local dev environment, turn it on and you'll get lots of details for every request you make.

Answer (score 2):

The New Relic Ruby agent spawns a background thread within each of your application's processes. These background threads collect data from your processes. The data is calculated into averages and sent to New Relic's servers every 60 seconds. As such, New Relic does not generate any "traffic" to your application. The slight overhead is due to New Relic using a small amount of your memory and CPU to keep track of average performance statistics. New Relic thoroughly tests the agent to ensure its overhead is minimal.

Comment: Is that background thread something like this web worker thing at Heroku? I mean does Heroku extra charge me for that or does it only use the resources I've set in settings? (Very small site here.)

Comment: Nope, Heroku does not charge for the background New Relic reporting thread. It's a thread, not a process.

Answer (score 1):

I have not dug into the Rack Middleware provided by Newrelic, but I don't believe they are using any sort of fancy asynchronous processing / sending of the stats.  They are likely using a Rack-based session though, which (from what I understand) can act as a sort of queue; it's just not as robust as solutions like Sidekiq or Resque.  So...there IS likely some overhead, but in my experience it is not significant.